# Что это за код цвета?

Tags: цвета, rgb

Подскажите, как называются такие цвета: `0xF2CFD4`? Существуют какие-либо таблицы таких цветов?

Comment: `HEX` цвета, просто `0x` тут участвует в роли `#`. То есть может быть `0xF2CFD4` а может быть так: `#F2CFD4`,

Comment: Цвета для сайта http://coderhs.com/archive/color_site

Comment: так же можно встретить 0x00000000 (8 знаков после x) где 2 последних будут значением альфа компонента (прозрачность)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ 2 первых, вроде.

Comment: @Эникейщик где как, судя по всему =) argb и rgba

Answer (score 0):

В компьютерной графике цвета принято задавать при помощи RGB-кодов (Red, Green, Blue). `0xF2CFD4` - это способ кодирования RGB, где

- `0x` - служебная часть,
- `F2` - тон красного в шестнадцатеричной системе (242 в десятичной)
- `CF` - тон зеленого в шестнадцатеричной системе (207 в десятичной)
- `D4` - тон синего в шестнадцатеричной системе (212 в десятичной)

Т.е. по одному байту на каждый цвет. Смешав эти цвета получим примерно такой цвет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Онлайн этот цвет можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/F2CFD4)

Comment: «В компьютерной графике цвета принято задавать при помощи RGB-кодов». RGB — все лишь одна из возможных цветовых моделей. «`0x` - служебная часть». Что еще за «служебная часть»? Это просто префикс шестнадцатеричного числа. «`F2` - тон красного». Обычно это компонентной называют, а не «тоном». Советую немного углубится в эту тему, может получится неплохой ответ.